# How to set Textwrangler the default editor for c code on OSX?

Tags: c, xcode, osx-mavericks, textwrangler, system-setting

Right from the start I found Xcode to be way to overloaded for simple C programs I have to write for university. Lately I discovered Textwrangler to be more of an editor I wanted to use for that purpose, beforehand I used VIM quite a lot, but having a mouse to navigate seems charming to me as well. So I tried setting Textwrangler the default editor for C code (I'm running Mavericks at the moment), but it won't keep the settings I make. The way I tried to set the editor as default is right-clicking on a C-file, clicking "Open with another app", choose "Textwrangler" and click "Always open with this app"; as already mentioned it does not keep the setting. I suspect Xcode to overwrite the setting, is there a way I can get around that?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I now found the answer myself - its just bloody stupid. Right click on any c-file, go to "Information", "Open With" section, choose TextWrangler and then click "Change all" - perhaps there is a more elegant way to do this via the Terminal, but that works, too. I just wonder why this does something different than the method I used before - seems rather senseless to me then.